# Game Dev Tycoon: error loading libXrandr

Tags: 13.04, games

I bought it from their site and got a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04. However, when I try to run Game Dev Tycoon from the terminal I get the following error:

```
gamedevtycoon: error while loading shared libraries: libXrandr.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386
```

I am getting some errors running this game as well (`error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0`). I have `libudev1` installed, it just won't run. There may have to be some manual linking.

EDIT:

There was some linking needed for mine:
[How do I resolve a "Cannot open shared object file libudev.so.0" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-in-ubuntu-64/288822#288822)

Answer (score 1):

It's a 32-bit program. I assume you're on 64-bit Ubuntu. You need the 32-bit libs.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

That gets me to the point where it runs. Except I just get a blue background and nothing happens. Hopefully you'll have better luck.

Comment: Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32ncurses5 lib32z1