# 'mount: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : no such file or directory' error while booting

Tags: boot, package-management, xubuntu

I was trying to load a version of CGminer which was returning a *libudev* type error, and followed a supposed solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-in-ubuntu-64) but it destroyed my system (so it seems).

I loaded the system in recovery mode from GRUB but all that done was actually tell me what I something is broken, do not know what to do next.

I think I somehow associated a *libudev.so.0* to 1 or 1 to 0, I am not sure what I did and how to fix it.

Comment: I think that a reinstallation would be easier.

Comment: Braiam - thanks for the comment , in this case not for me - before the helpful answer was deleted - I checked and libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb is only 26 or so k large - as i have said (and did say before it was deleted) I only have wireless at the moment and I have both upgraded this system and added the drivers - so much easier for me to try to fix the broken link.

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to install LightTable on 12.04. This solution fixed my boot problem but I did have to run:-
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
because dpkg was giving lock file errors. Given up installing LightTable!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see that some of the solutions posted on the other question overwrite `libudev.so.0`, because of the `-f` option supplied to `ln`. This is not due to malicious intent, but because these solutions were designed for newer versions of Ubuntu, in which the libudev1 package is used. The solution creates `libudev.so.0` symbolic link. But in 12.04, libudev0 is used. So the `libudev.so.0` library file is overwritten with a broken symbolic link to `libudev.so.1` which doesn't exist. The solutions should not have included the `-f` option for `ln` in the command line, which overwrites files.

Enough of the explanation, here is a solution:

Basically the library file is replaced with a broken symbolic link. Start in recovery mode and select the root shell option. Then run this command: `apt-get install libudev0`. Once you are done, type exit and reboot. If you are using WiFi, [download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libudev0/download) the libudev0 package and copy it into a USB drive. Then in the root shell in recovery, plug the USB drive and run: (tip: you can use `Tab` to autocomplete many things, including file paths )

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw / # (re)mount the filesystem in read-write mode.
mkdir /media/usb
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
dpkg -i /media/usb/path_to_package_file
```

Then reboot and hopefully your system should work.

Comment: what if the file system is read-only?

Comment: @kapitanluffy Correct, I will update the solution.

Comment: On my machine, `apt-get install libudev0` did not work, because `libudev.so.0` already existed but it was symlinked to an invalid file (it throws the same error message). Simply fixing the symlink worked, example: `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu; ln -sf libudev.so.1.6.9 libudev.so.0` (make sure the correct `libudev.so.x.x.x` actually exists in that directory).