# 'mount: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : no such file or directory'

Tags: boot, mount

I got this error while booting

```
'mount: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : no such file or directory'
```

Then i followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354837/mount-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libudev-so-0-no-such-file-or-dir)

I Booted into recovery mode and opened terminal and installed libudev0 using
    apt-get install libudev0

It says its already installed

Even i linked libudev0 and libudev1 as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error)
But no gain :(

EDIT: Output of locate -e libudev.so.0

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `locate -e libudev.so.0`

Comment: @terdon Posted the output of locate -e libudev.so.0

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64bit system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you *are* running a 64bit system. If so, this dirty hack should work:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

That will crate a link named `libudev.so.0` that points to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0`.

Comment: gives error. ln:failed to create symbolic link. '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0 ' : File exists

Comment: @viks did you copy the exact command? It sounds like you ran `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` instead.

Comment: ya i used the exact command , thanks for your help , used -f flag with the command and it worked

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem on ubuntu 12.04 x64, solved it fast 
first remounting  with

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

then locating the `libudev.so.0`

```
locate -e libudev.so.0
```

then doin the "dirty trick"

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

worked perfectly to me,
  thanx Terdon!

Comment: Welcome to AU! Please don't post "thank you" messages. The answer section should be reserved for, well… answers. Once you have enough reputation you can [vote for other answers](/help/privileges/vote-up), that you find helpful or worthwhile.