# Why does Ubuntu 12.04 Boot To Black Screen after updating Chromium?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, chromium

I was running Ubuntu  12.04 LTS for 64 bit systems on a dual boot custom computer with Windows 7. It was functioning normally for at least 3 days before I noticed that Youtube videos were flickering on my screen in Chromium. My first thought was to update flash, and since flash comes with the latest version of chrome, I tried updating my Chromium installation. At first I tried using the Chromium Updater Extension, but it didn't solve the problem. It was somewhere around this time that Chromium stopped opening completely. I then tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chromium, but it still wouldn't open. I tried running the program from the command line, but got a message involving "libudev.so.0" being missing from the operating system. I believe after this I had to leave so I shut down the computer.

The next day, I tried loading the Ubuntu installation, only to see that it was stuck on the purple screen. After waiting a while, I tried restarting it and loading it again. This time, it only booted to a black screen with a blinking line at the top left of the screen, much like a terminal window. I tried removing all the non essential USB devices but it still wouldn't boot.

I did attempt to use the Boot-Repair Graphical Tool, but it said that it encoutered an error and gave me this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7306456/ .  Ubuntu still won't boot at this point, and I'd rather not have to reinstall it a third time. I did try Repairing Grub2 via the live CD terminal as accoridng to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_the_LiveCD_terminal , but i'm a bit nervous about removing the Grub entirely. Won't that make it difficult for me to boot windows? Also, I can't remember exactly when but I got that same message about libudev.so.0 being missing again at some point when trying to boot. Probably after using Boot-Repair.

April 23 - I did try enabling boot messages to see if anything useful came up, and I got two messages at the very end that looked important.

`ureadahead main process (312) terminated with status 5
mountall main process (319) terminated with status 127`

I did try looking up solutions, but the ones I found sounded very sketchy and all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

After some work, I managed to get the desktop back by following the directions here:

['mount: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : no such file or directory' error while booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354837/mount-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libudev-so-0-no-such-file-or-dir)

In recovery, start a root shell and remount the partition read-write

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Install the missing package

```
apt-get install libudev
```

Reboot and all is OK