# Trying to resolve “Cannot open shared object file libudev.so.0”? Getting too many levels of symbolic links problem

Tags: symbolic-link, shared-library

I was trying to solve the problem highlighted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error):

But whenever I execute

```
 ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

or even

```
 ln -s libudev.so.0 libudev.so.1
```

I get `Too many symbolic links` error.

I know i'll have to redo the symbolic links, but how?

Answer (score 0):

First try to find which `libudev` you have and where it is:

```
sudo find / -name "libudev.so*"
```

If you find `libudev.so.1`, note its path, and link:

```
sudo ln -s <libudevpath>/libudev.so.1 <libudevpath>/libudev.so.0
```

Do not try to link the other direction!

`ln -s file1 file0` creates a symbolic link between two files. Whenever an application looks for `file0` (which doesn't really exist!), it will follow this link and use `file1` instead.

Let me know if I was helpful enough.