# How do I install and run programs on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded a program called piskel [from here](https://github.com/juliandescottes/piskel/wiki/Desktop-applications) and I have no idea how to run it or install it. This are the files that where inside:

[image]

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I saw that the package on running from terminal shows:

```
./piskel: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, on 15.04 this package is not available (I suspect other previous version  it is missing as well) to fix this I found this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/288822/47291

<sub>**quick warning, a comment in the other post said not to do this, but didn't say why, so it might cause unintended things to happen, just a heads up incase**</sub>

You basically need to link `libudev.so.1` to `libudev.so.0`

For 32 bit run this in terminal:

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

For 64 bit run this:

```
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```