# How do I install/run PISKEL after it was downloaded?

Tags: software-installation, downloads

**I downloaded a program called Piskel and I can't figure out how to activate it.**

I am *trying* to make a game on Linux Ubuntu and struggling immensely. I needed sprites for the game and they would help me visualize what was happening while testing and such. I looked around online and found a pixel art program called Pixel...

I had seen the program before but didn't think anything of it. When I decided to test it out, and watch a few online videos on how it worked, I fell in love. Unfortunately, I won't always have access to the online version. I sought a downloadable version and discovered they had one for Linux computers!

**I clicked download, downloaded it as a ".zip" file, extracted the files and now I don't know what to do.**

For the record, yes. I did try to download the Windows version and use Wine but it kept getting an error.

**How do I run it and is there a step I'm missing? If so, what is it?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install and run programs on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620205/how-do-i-install-and-run-programs-on-ubuntu)

Comment: sorry a link to a google drive is pretty dubious. I removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running it is straightforward.

1. Double click the downloaded zip file and unzip the package to your home directory. This will create a directory `Piskel-0.11.0-64bits`.
2. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
3. Enter`cd Piskel-0.11.0-64bits`.
4. Enter `./piskel`.

The Piskel window appears.
Unfortunately, this program does not follow application standards so there is no easy way to add this to your launcher.

You need to tell the operating system where to look for the `piskel` command. In this case, that is the current directory, indicated by `.`. So the command `./piskel` means "look in the current directory and execute the program `piskel` located there".

Comment: Hello sir, what does cd mean and how do I do that?

Comment: @J.Sabere `cd` changes the working directory in the terminal. Type `man cd` for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, that method didn't work. It replied with:                          'user@system-63626a:~$ cd Piskel-0.11.0-64bits
user@system-63626a:~/Piskel-0.11.0-64bits$ piskel
piskel: command not found
user@system-63626a:~/Piskel-0.11.0-64bits$ '

Comment: @J.Sabere There is an excellent (and free) online course [Introduction to Linux](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-1) from the Linux Foundation available on EdX if you'd like to learn more about the basics of using Linux.

Comment: +sempaiscuba  I'll give it a look, I really want to grow more at home with Linux and this is getting old _really_ fast.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Jos  Thank you, this time it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

To just run Piskel @Jos solution works, but I found this annoying so I set it as an alias:

1. if not present create "bash_aliases" file in the home ("~")
   directory
2. add the alias, e.g.:

   ```
    alias piskel='pathtofolder/piskel'
   ```
3. open any terminal and type "piskel" and it should open.
4. To make it work in currently open terminals, type:

   ```
    source .bashrc
   ```

I still ran into the problem @Jos mentioned about adding it to the launcher, and when I pass it a .piskel file I get a error, but I hope this helps!

Sources:
[How can I create an alias so that when I enter "kt" it executes "killall gnome-terminal"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18787/how-can-i-create-an-alias-so-that-when-i-enter-kt-it-executes-killall-gnome-t)

Answer (score 0):

In my Linux Lite i do that way:

Right click on the Piskel file; 
Open with another application; 
Use a personalized code(command); 
Write in the text box:

```
cd /home/<user>/<path_to_piskel_directory>/piskel
```

Now its open with double-click.

if it dont work, right-click "Make file executable".

If you enter in the open with another application again, the piskel will be there, now you can use it to open Piskel projects.

The name "Open with another application" and "Use a personalized code" can be wrong, i am from Brazil and use Linux in portuguese, so try to search same-meaning words. (:P)

Answer (score -1):

just create a script .sh on folder of you have decompress **Piskel**

*for example:*

/home/myname/myprogs/Piskel.0.1.0/

create your .sh here with this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ${0%/*}
`./piskel`
```

now you can move folder, if you change version just copy paste the .sh
You can easily create a shortcut now!