# Undefined reference to udev_new

Tags: 16.04, libraries, udev, linux-headers

I am currently trying to test a c++ code I wrote on Qt, and I downloaded libudev and it keeps giving a lot of "undefined reference to". I followed almost all of the posts of upgrading libudev,

```
sudo apt-get install libudev0:i386
sudo ln -sf /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/$(arch)-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

and this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error) .Error from this:

```
dpkg: error processing archive libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
dkpk: error processing archive libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
libudev0_175-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb
```

I haven't had any luck yet. Most of the time I get "directory does not exist" errors. Would this have to do with my Ubuntu version?

Comment: Have you installed `libudev-dev` and setup its linking in Qt project.

Comment: @user.dz I have download libudev-dev. How do I set up its linking in Qt project?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project , I'm not sure about default paths and how Qt handle flags but `-I`, `-l`, `-L`  should be the same for any c++ compiler.

Comment: Got it.
I added 
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
DEFINES += LINK_LIBUDEV
PKGCONFIG += libudev 
to my  .pro file and it worked.
THANKS

Comment: That's nice, it does support pkgconfig .. that's new to me. Would you please write an answer to to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. I added 
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig 
DEFINES += LINK_LIBUDEV 
PKGCONFIG += libudev to my .pro file and it worked