# Unable to run apps installed from the snap-store

Tags: 20.04, snap

Yesterday I was installing Watchman from Facebook and I mysterious broke something.

Whenever I run a program installed with  snap-store it throws this Error:

```
/snap/snapd/11107/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I have tried all possible solutions I found online but they are not working.

Comment: What exactly did you try so far? Please edit your question and tell us what tutorials / steps you've tried, and what was the outcome.

Comment: `ls -al  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` any output?

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jan  6 22:47 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.17
` this is the output @nobody

Comment: @Pizza When you search for the same error on StackExchange you get a lot of answers which does not work on my machine

Comment: any helpful here?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/288821/how-do-i-resolve-a-cannot-open-shared-object-file-libudev-so-0-error

Comment: `E: Package 'libudev0:i386' has no installation candidate`
 this is the output @nobody

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`  and `sudo apt update`

Comment: Still i am getting the same Error `E: Package 'libudev0:i386' has no installation candidate` @nobody

Comment: `sudo apt install libudev1:i386`

Comment: I installed this package what is next ? @nobody

Comment: because that package did not solve the issue

Comment: This goes to @nobody and actually all you have suggested is true and other solutions i found were also true but they forget to mention that you need to reload the configurations using this command  `sudo ldconfig /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer for anybody to use it - and also accept the answer.